# Custom Posts Types using Posts Category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm using some custom posts types, and, I don't wanna create specific categories for each one.

I'd like to use the Post Category in all my Custom Post.

Here is a example of my new custom posts type:

I know how create new category type for my custom posts, but I don't know how use the regular categories from posts.

```
/*  New Custom Post - Cupons
/* ------------------------------------ */

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_cupons' );
function create_post_type_cupons() {
    register_post_type( 'cupom',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Cupons' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Cupom' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) mentions a `taxonomies` parameter, giving it a value of `array( 'category' )` will do what you want.

There is also the `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` function

Answer (score 1):

After

```
'public' => true,
```

you add

```
'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag'),
```

this one create category and tag for your custom post type if you want just category the delete ,'post_tag'.

Answer (score 1):

I added the function `register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, $object_type )` in `functions.php`.

First: I need to choose which kind of taxonomy I want, in this case, "category".

Second: I choose the object type, in this case, "cupom" that is my Custom Post Type.

```
add_action('init','add_categories_to_cupom');
function add_categories_to_cupom(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'cupom');
}
```

So now, my Custom Post Type "cupom" uses the the Posts Category.

Comment: Please expand upon this answer by including an explanation of the code. (Also, there is no "above". The stack supports mupliple ways to sort answers)